# odoo: user cannot read from an object

Tags: odoo

In odoo a user cannot read from an object `sale.order` 
he is in the group Warehouse/manager has rights: `read and write`  on `sale.order` 
I got this in the shell:

```
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(Console)
>>> so=self.pool.get('sale.order').browse(self._cr, 60, 100)
>>> so.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 820, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 913, in determine_value
    record._prefetch_field(self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3246, in _prefetch_field
    result = self.read(list(fnames), load='_classic_write')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3191, in read
    values[name] = field.convert_to_read(record[name], use_name_get)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5641, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 813, in __get__
    return record._cache[self]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 6024, in __getitem__
    return value.get() if isinstance(value, SpecialValue) else value
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 55, in get
    raise self.exception
AccessError: ('AccessError', u'The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: sale.order, Operation: read)')
```

do you have any idea about this problem ?

Comment: For reading a Sales order, we must to give a access right of *Sales* rather to give *Warehouse*

Comment: yes there is already access right to the group for Sales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the following rules for Access Rights in Odoo.

`Global rules are subtractive, they must all be matched for a record to be accessible`

`Group rules are additive, if any of them matches (and all global rules match) then the record is accessible`

So what you basically need to do here is the following:

Head to Settings -> Security -> Record Rules use search to search for "object contains sale.order"

Now try activating/de-activating certain rules to see which one of them causes the issue. From what I remember there is a rule that does not allow a user to see orders he has not created.

Start from there

Comment: you are right, the group wasn't on the allowed record rules of the object sale.order

Comment: Hello, i have same issue. I'm try your advice. But not working, What's wrong on me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549824/access-right-for-users-odoo